# Visual studio online destroy file

Tags: c#, rest, powershell, tfs, azure-devops

How can I destroy a file with history in visual studio online?

I want to both delete the file and the history.

Can I use the GUI or rest-api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can use the tf.exe commandline tool for this. Just open Visual Studio Developer command prompt and then write: tf destroy "item".

You can see the full docs for the destroy command here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension that enables you to "destroy" things from Source Control Explorer.

It's called the [TFS Source Control Explorer Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af70cbb7-1e0d-4d16-bc57-cccc15370c51).

[image]